# how to make a description on a SAS code automatically

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I want to know if there is a SAS code that allows you to give a description in the log or in a txt file on a SAS program (The conditions made in the program, the input and output tables.. ...) ?

Comment: Isn't that want SAS generates into the SAS log when you run the program?  Pease explain what you mean.  An example would probably help make it clearer.

Comment: I want something that allows to give an analysis of the SAS code, (example the program does what, the input and output tables, the conditions used in the program .......)

Comment: You can throw it in ChatGPT and see what it does, but that's still a manual task as far as I know.

Comment: Given various dynamic programming methods, you can't always look at a .sas program and know what the input and output tables are.  If you run the program, and then process the log, you might have more luck.  But when you ask 'the program does what', I think you're back to a human reading the code (or sure, try  your favorite LLM for a guess).

Answer (score 1):

Use `Proc SCAPROC`

From documentation:

> What Does the SCAPROC Procedure Do?
>
> The SCAPROC procedure implements the SAS Code Analyzer, which captures information about input, output, and the use of macro symbols from a SAS job while it is running. The SAS Code Analyzer can write this information and the information thatis in the original SAS file to a file that you specify. The SCAPROC procedure can also generate a grid-enabled job that can concurrently run independent pieces of the job. You can issue the SCAPROC procedure on your operating system's command line or in SAS code in the SAS Editor window.

Comment: Proc SCAPROC , it is limited, it does not analyze all SAS code, it does not give the conditions used in the code for example (where , if ......)

Comment: True, but better than nothing.  You can blend with a log parse for some more insight.  Even together, sometimes they are not enough insight for troubleshooting and hardcoded logging is needed.